# How to link an other eclipse perspective when clicking on a file in package explorer?

Tags: eclipse, file, package, explorer, perspective

I have **2 screens** : the first one displays a file (in a file editor), and the other one (in a new eclipse window) displaying the package explorer. When I click on a file in the package explorer, it opens the file in the current perspective instead of my perspective with the editor. How to link the package explorer to a composant or a perspective ?